# Issues getting NTLM authentication in an intranet app on IIS6 w/IE 9

Tags: iis, web-parts, ntlm, intranet

I have an intranet web app running in a virtual directory on a Win 2003 server. I would like to have the app pick up the user name for personalization.

In the web.config I have set the following:

`<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false"/> 
    <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
    <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>`

In IIS 6 I have set directory Security set to Integrated Windows authentication and have Enable Anonymous access disabled. 
In IE9 I have the site address set in the local intranet zone and Integrated Windows Authentication enabled.

If I access the site with Chrome or FF I get a login prompt and I can enter the username/password and everything works but if I go to the site with IE9 I get a 401 error.

The goal is to pickup the username so that I can do personalization of web parts and log access to certain areas.

Any ideas on how to make this work?  Chrome and FF are not options, IE is our standard.

TIA
J

Comment: Is the user you're trying to access the site with in the same domain as the site?

Comment: Yes. Any of the users are in the AD for the domain. The server is inside our firewall.

Comment: Within the intranet zone in IE check the following: Tools > Internet options > Security tab > Custom level > Scroll to the bottom > User Authentication, Logon